# how do I fix ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error in oracle 10g

Tags: sql

I have a database schema employee like this:

```
create table Employee  
(  
   ID int,  
   Name varchar(20),  
   Salary float,  
   Department varchar(20)  
) ;
```

but when I run this following query at oracle 10g, I get the following error:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

The query is

```
select min(salary) 
from (select distinct top 3 salary 
      from employee 
      order by salary desc
     );
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `select top` is not an oracle expression.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff for your kind attention. Would you please explain me what's the effect of using where rownum <= 3

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you would express this as:

```
select min(salary)
from (select distinct salary
      from employee e
      order by salary desc
     ) s
where rownum <= 3;
```

`select top` is a SQL extension associated with SQL Sever (although used by a few other databases as well).

In Oracle 12C, you would not need a subquery:

```
select distinct salary
from employee
order by salary desc
offset 2 rows fetch next 1 row only
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon Linoff for your kind attention. Would you please explain me what's the effect of using where rownum <= 3

Comment: @user9817940 . . . It does the same thing in Oracle that `select top 3` does in SQL Server.  It selects the "first" three rows.